# words after the same in string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am a newbie to xcode and maybe this question is silly but I am lagging with my home work.
 In a file I want to read a specific character after the string.

example:

```
asasasasasas
wewewewewewe
xyz_ 22 aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd
fgfgfgfgfgfgfg
ererererererer

abc_ 12 bbbbbbbbbb dddddddd
jkjkjkjkjkjkjk
lalallalalalal
```

Mycode:

```
NSString *contentFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathFile    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *lineFile = [contentFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableString *xmlFile = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(int i = 2; i < lineFile.count; i++)//i = 2 for don't take the 2 first line
{
    if ([((NSString *)[lineFile objectAtIndex:i]) rangedOfString:@"test"].location !=  NSNotFound){
        xmlFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<nameTag>%@</nameTag>", xmlFile, (NSString *)[lineFile objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else if ...
}
```

everything works fine ..
 but i want to print after                                                                            xyz_ ... like :

```
aaaaaaaaaaa 
bbbbbbbbbbb 
ccccccccccccccc 
ddddddddddddd
```

Comment: kindly explain your question and requirement once again with 2 examples. And i formatted your question, did i miss something?

Comment: i want to print the the character after "xyz_"  i want to print all the charachter which contains space in between each character like after xyz_:
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
ccccccc



dont say "NSArray *lineFile = [contentFile componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].. i tried its not working

Comment: Do you want to print "22 aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd" in your example?

Comment: as in your question you have: xyz_ 22 aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd
fgfgfgfgfgfgfg
ererererererer, what you want in you output? only aaaaaaa                                   
bbbbbbb                            
cccccc ? What about dddddd ?

Comment: ya dude i want to print all the character having space  after xyz_22 till before abc_12

Comment: unless you are not confirm to your desired output, we cant help you out. input file shows dozens of a, b, c, d with few more texts, output shows only 5 a, b, c where are rest?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya check i edited

Answer (score 1):

> everything works fine ..
> but i want to print after xyz_ ... like :
>
> aaaaaaaaaaa
> bbbbbbbbbbb
> ccccccccccccccc
> ddddddddddddd

I hope to have understood correctly what you want to do:

```
if ([([lineFile objectAtIndex:i]) rangedOfString:@"test"].location !=  NSNotFound)
{
    xmlFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<nameTag>%@</nameTag>", xmlFile, (NSString *)[lineFile objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSString* str= [[lineFile objectAtIndex: i]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"xyz_ " withString: @""];
    NSLog(@"%@",[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @"\n"]);
}
```

Comment: thanks :) i tried this it works, but i want to put each line a tag for ex :

<aaa>aaaaaaaaa<aaa>
<bbb>bbbbbbbbb<bbb>
<ccc>ccccccccc<ccc>
<ddd>ddddddddd<ddd>

Comment: Is that only an example? You should explain precisely the rule of how tags should be added.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this as well: (would recommend to try in a separate test app)

I am assuming your target line:

```
xyz_ 22 aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd
```

always starts with "xyz_ 22". Check out here: (see comments also)

```
    // prepared a string similar to what you already have
    NSMutableString *xmlfile = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@",
    @"asasasasasas",
    @"wewewewewewe",
    @"xyz_ 22 aaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd",
    @"fgfgfgfgfgfgfg",
    @"ererererererer",
    @"",
    @"abc_ 12 bbbbbbbbbb dddddddd",
    @"jkjkjkjkjkjkjk",
    @"lalallalalalal"];

    NSLog(@"%@", xmlfile);    // check out by printing (optional)

    NSArray *arr = [xmlfile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];  // first break with NEWLINE character
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);         // check out by printing (optional)


 for (NSString *str in arr)    // traverse all lines
{
    if([str hasPrefix:@"xyz_ 22"])  // if it starts with "xyz_ 22"
    {

        NSMutableArray *mArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"xyz_ 22 " withString:@""] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];

         for(int i=0; i< [mArr count];i++ )
         {
            NSString *tag;

            if([[mArr objectAtIndex:i] length] > 3)
            {
                // If more than three i.e., aaaaa then write <aaa>aaaaaaa<aaa>
                tag = [[mArr objectAtIndex:i] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
            }
            else
            {
                // If less than three i.e., aa then pick <aa>aa<aa> or 
                                            a  then pick <a>a<a>
                tag = [mArr objectAtIndex:i];
            }

            NSString *s= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<%@>%@<%@>", tag, [mArr objectAtIndex:i], tag];
            [mArr removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [mArr insertObject:s atIndex:i];

        }

        NSLog(@"%@", mArr);   // prints output
    }
}
```

If start of line do not fixed with "xyz_ 22", you need to have a look at [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class and use it instead of using `hasPrefix`.

This sample pattern can help you:

```
@"^(.{3}\_\s*\d{2}\s*)"
```

This pattern matches any line that has three characters followed by an underscore and space(s) followed by two digits followed by space(s).

You can use either of these functions then as per your need:

[firstMatchInString:options:range:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/matchesInString%3aoptions%3arange%3a)

[matchesInString:options:range:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/firstMatchInString%3aoptions%3arange%3a)

[numberOfMatchesInString:options:range:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/firstMatchInString%3aoptions%3arange%3a)

Hope it helps.

Happy coding and reading!!!

**EDIT:**

I have updated code but i have doubt on the no. of characters in a tag you specified in comment. well this will give you an idea on how to work around this issue.

Comment: thanks :) i tried this it works, but i want to put each line a tag for ex : <aaa>aaaaaaaaa<aaa> <bbb>bbbbbbbbb<bbb> <ccc>ccccccccc<ccc> <ddd>ddddddddd<ddd>

Comment: @DD007, Check out my updates, I have updated the code and a new for loop is added which amend value as per the requirement.

Comment: ya  thanks i finished my homework ... but small help .. it  prints <aaa>aaaaaaaa<aaa> then <aaa>bbbbbbb<aaa> that tag is same .. but i want different tag for each space like <bbb>bbbbb<bbb> then <ccc>cccccc<cccc>> for all space .... and how to read abc_12 after xyz_ and(its sub file "fgfgfgfgfgf" and "ererererere"... this is my last question for my home work

Comment: Hmmm. may be you missed something but if you 'll notice this line `tag = [mArr objectAtIndex:i];` it always refer to ith element of array to use inside a tag. please double check it. didn't get your second question.

Comment: NSString *s= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@<aaa>%@%<aaa>", tag, [mArr objectAtIndex:i], tag];

ya user1873574 .. but how to change the tag for each line EX:

<aaa>aaaaaa<aaa>
<bbb>bbbbbb<bbb>
<ccc>cccccc<ccc>

......... bcoz its printing same tag for all line like <aaa>aaaaaa<aaa>
<aaa>bbbbbb<aaa>
<aaa>cccccc<aaa> ... sorry my question might be silly ... m just learning

Comment: `initWithFormat:@"%@<aaa>%@%<aaa>"` should be `initWithFormat:@"<%@>%@<%@>"`

Comment: thanks i got my grade ... i have one doubt if i want to change different tag name like:
 <123>aaaaaa<123> <hi>bbbbbb<hi> <good>cccccc<good>
 how to do this ..

Comment: you can initialize `tag` variable with `your value` instead of `tag = [mArr objectAtIndex:i];`

Comment: it depends on what value you want to print in tag. if you will see the if block in second for loop, you will find that `tag` is being set there, instead of this way you can set `tag` with for example 123.

Answer (score 0):

String  "test" is not present in the string to be formatted .Try to remove it and then try with [contentFile  componentsSeparatedByString@" "]

Comment: thanks :) i tried this it works, but i want to put each line a tag for ex : <aaa>aaaaaaaaa<aaa> <bbb>bbbbbbbbb<bbb> <ccc>ccccccccc<ccc> <ddd>ddddddddd<ddd>

Comment: Take first three characters of each elements you get from componentsSeparatedByString and last three add whatever tag you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break the string by new line, try this one :

```
NSArray *lineFile=[contentFile componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

instead of

```
NSArray *lineFile = [contentFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```